# Replace class from input with php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Help, i need to replace a class from a !input! with preg_replace.

My code is:

```
$v = '
<div class="inputbox">
<input type="text" name="inputbox" class="inputbox" autocomplete="off" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="inputbox open based">
<input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="inputbox label" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
</div>
';
```

I need get:

```
$v_complete = '
<div class="inputbox">
<input type="text" name="inputbox" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="form-control open based">
<input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="label form-control" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
</div>
';
```

Thnx!

Comment: it's a syntax error: parse error

Comment: Do you really have a DOUBLE-QUOTED string literal containing double quotes **?????** Please make you example make sence

Comment: The string is terminated prematurely due to the doublequotes inside the HTML. Use [PHP Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to omit this problem.

Comment: Double quotes are not important, I showed an example of its task

Comment: what does "poniamete" mean by the way? I hope it's not an insulting word.

Comment: Whatever it was you called me. _I am most certainly not_

Comment: @RiggsFolly It seems like he doesn't want to say, so it's assumed that it was an insult in his language.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v_complete = preg_replace('#(input.*class="[^"]*)inputbox([\s"])#', '$1form-control$2', $v);
```